# I don't see silverlight tab (and controls) after I've installed Silverlight 4 tools for visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I've just **successfully** installed Silverlight 4 tools for visual studio 2010. But I can't see any Silverlight tab in the tools box. Is there any configuration I need to proceed to.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new project in C# or VB. you should see an option to create a silverlight project and you will then be able to see the new controls in the toolbox.

Edit:
It looks like you go about it in a different way. Try creating a Silverlight application then select type as ASP.NET-MVC

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was not enough explicit. I'd like to have those silverlight controls to appear on webform page. I'm doing a walk-through from a "Stephen Walther" blog on how to use silverlight media-control in asp.net mvc. Here's the link: http://stephenwalther.com/Blog/archive/2008/09/03/asp-net-mvc-application-building-family-video-website-3-play-videos-with-silverlight.aspx

Comment: According to his blog, Silverlight toolbox should appear when while working on a ASP.NET MVC projet. I just don't see how I could do that.

Comment: I don't see it either. It looks like he was using Silverlight 3 tools for visual studio 2008 with visual studio 2008. There may have been some changes.